Compare two tables row wise using Q/kdb
I would like to compare data from two tables with same columns. What I think is I can use match operator (~) between the tables in each row of those tables, however, If the table size is big I am getting timeout issues.
For example: This is the table I have:
tab1:([] col1:1 2 3; col2: `a`b`c)
tab2:([] col1:1 3 5; col2: `a`d`b)

tab1~tab2 on each row taking timeout if the data is huge
Tried each row comparision

how big are your tables? How many rows/columns? Are they in-memory or on-disk?

You could try comparing column by column too, exiting early if a mismatch is found.

as suggested - do by column, (or groups of) tab1[col1colX ... ] ~ tab2[col1colX ...]

Who controls the timeout?

Are you trying to determine if the tables are equal, or look for differences in the tables? is it enough that count[tab1] = count[tab2] ? Are the tables sorted? parted? Is it enough to do an md5sum of the data?

One way is to reduce the amount of the data. For example, compare tables column by column or split tables into chunks. For a partitioned table, it can be partition by partition comparison.
Another way is to check the timeout \T and increase it. I do not recommend doing this because a timeout was set on purpose and with big enough tables you can destroy an instance.
The answer depends on the data structure, amount of data, and resources that you have and can be done in manual mode or with a simple lambda function
